# How to define a Complex matrix in Polar form in Matlab

Tags: matlab

This question may well be very simple but it's not clear to me how to do this from the Matlab documentation.

I need to create W, a unitary matrix

In complex form the j,k th entry [W]_j,k of W is:

[W]_j,k = 1/sqrt(n)exp^(2*pi*i*j*k/n) j,k = 1, 2, . , n

How can I define such a matrix in Matlab, life will be easier if i can do everything in polar form.

Baz

Comment: Create a function handle `fn=@(j,k)(1/sqrt...)` then use `bsxfun(@fn,(1:n),(1:n)')` to get the matrix

Comment: Can you show me what the function should be (sorry but I really don't know hot to handle complex numbers in matlab at all!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution using `bsxfun`:

```
n=4;
fn=@(a,b)(1/sqrt(n)*exp(2*pi*1i*a*b/n));
bsxfun(fn,(1:n),(1:n)')

ans =

   0.0000 + 0.5000i  -0.5000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.5000i   0.5000 - 0.0000i
  -0.5000 + 0.0000i   0.5000 - 0.0000i  -0.5000 + 0.0000i   0.5000 - 0.0000i
  -0.0000 - 0.5000i  -0.5000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.5000i   0.5000 - 0.0000i
   0.5000 - 0.0000i   0.5000 - 0.0000i   0.5000 - 0.0000i   0.5000 - 0.0000i
```

There is nothing special about imaginary numbers in matlab. But one advice: Dont use the variable names i and j. i and j are both the imaginary unit.

Comment: Good, but another useful piece of advice demonstrated in dagcilibili's answer is to use `1i` instead of `i` when imaginary is needed so you always get `0.0000 + 1.0000i` even when `i` is redefined.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this would solve it:

```
N = 4;
[X Y] = meshgrid(1:N);
W = exp(1i*2*pi*X.*Y/N)/sqrt(N)
```

Comment: Sorry I can't give you both the full credit but Daniel R was first with the original answer so that's what I based it on

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved just with matrix multiplication and then (element-wise) exponentiation:

```
1/sqrt(n)*exp(2*pi*1i/n*(1:n).'*(1:n))
```

Comment: Vector outer product to the rescue. Good catch. +1